# Don't see my class "well" into "row"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

everybody.

I'm working on a well-class insertion and it worked perfectly in the lesson... Then I tried it for a project on my own but the "well" classes don't appear. 
I do have my 2 x 3 buttons but they are not side by side as they should. 
Normally, the "well" classes should appear as two rectangles side by side with 3  buttons inside each but they don't.
I only have my buttons 3 ones above the 3 others.

This is what I coded :

```
<div class="container-fluid"/>
  <a href="http://www.willandjoan.com/contact">CONTACT</a>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="well">
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="well">
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
    </div>  
  </div>        
</div>
```

Maybe I forgot something to activate Bootstrap properly ?
Has anyone an idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - what's not working? I've created an example here - http://www.bootply.com/SKdSzVAtFi - is that the effect that you're after?

Comment: Right, Gareth ! But I tried your code and it doesn't work...

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? I.e. What's the issue at the moment and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to put the social medias icons side by side (i.e horizontally) on the right side of the page and at the same level as the "contact" link (which place is on the left).

My problems are the followings : 

- the icons are one line below the "contact" link,
- I wanted to use the "well" class to place the icons horizontally but instead, the effect is vertical and I don't understand why ! 

I hope I'm precise enough... thanks for your time !